# Passing parameters to map functions in CouchDb

Tags: javascript, nosql, couchdb

I wonder if we could pass variables as parameters to a map function in CouchDb.

Practically, I have a database with coordinates of places, and I only want to map/reduce the places that are within reach of a point. How could I do that? I want something like:

```
function(doc, x, y, radius) {
  if (doc.x - x)^2 + (doc.y - y)^2 < radius^2 {
    emit(doc._id, doc);
  }
}
```

How can we do that in CouchDb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Use [GeoCouch](http://vmx.cx/cgi-bin/blog/index.cgi/geocouch-the-future-is-now%3A2010-05-03%3Aen,CouchDB,Python,Erlang,geo) since you're doing geo-spatial queries
2. Write up separate view indexes for each of your locations
3. Use a [list function](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List#Listing_Views_with_CouchDB_0.10_and_later) on a view that maps all your relevant documents (you can pass parameters via querystring to the list function)

Comment: The list function looks promising because GeoCouch isn't yet supported by heroku. I'll give it a shot now.